# How to pass dynamic Fields in the Select query for a db connector of Mule-4

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am a beginner in Mulesoft and want to know how can I pass a dynamic field in a select query.
please help to construct a dynamic query with respect to the API query parameters (by using a database connector)

if my API URL looks like as below

```
**https://localhost:9103/api?param1=empname,empid,empnumber**
```

And my select query must be as below

```
 **Select empname,empid,empnumber from employeetable**
```

**Note: I am using mule4 and Anypoint Studio version 7.4**

Comment: In case you are not aware doing that exposes your application to an SQL injection vulnerability. That is very much a security risk and absolutely not recommended. See https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection for an explanation, though there hundreds of pages explaining SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Sudhan - Are you planning to build/expose an API that would take in empname, empid and empnumber from your API consumer in your query param1 and in you flow, fire a backend database query which would then be returned as a response back to the API consumer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL must be like this when you would hit the Mule API.

```
https://localhost:9103/api?param1=empname,empid,empnumber
```

In your mule application, after listener please use `set variable component from mule palette`

```
<set-variable value="#[message.attributes.queryParams.param1 as String]" doc:name="Set Variable" variableName="columns"/>
```

Then in your query component use this variable as I write below,

**In query section :-**

```
select :fields from employeetable
```

**In Parameters section (in fx mode):-**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    "fields" : vars.columns
}
```

you will get the query as you want

```
Select empname,empid,empnumber from employeetable
```